# How is a Butterfly Labs Bitforce Single powered?

Tags: fpga, butterfly-labs

[Its website](http://www.butterflylabs.com/product-details/) says it uses 80W of power, so that's too much for a USB port. How does it receive it's power?

Can it run on a 240V power supply, or does it need 110V?

Note I'm not asking about the newer "Bitforce Single (SC)", which hasn't been shipped to anyone yet. This the older (FPGA?) hardware that has been sold for some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses ~70W @ 12V of external power. The stock power brick is cheaply made, giant, and inefficient (PF=.5,efficiency~.8). Fortunately, the power brick can run on 240V.  Many people make their own cables to use an ATX or bench PSU (with higher powerfactor and efficiency)

source: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=67819.msg796852#msg796852

Comment: Yes it can. IIRC, it's the standard 100-250V 50-60Hz